# Use PHP to copy partial MySQL column data to another

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have an "additional images" column in my mySQL DB, and I am (so far unsuccessfully) attempting to copy JUST the first URL to another column as the "main image"

For example:

```
http://website.com/img1.jpg,http://website.com/img2.jpg,http://website.com/img3.jpg,etc..
```

There are no quotation marks around these images, and the db is updated automatically via feed, so simply manually updating each is out of the question.

I have some PHP code:

```
$query5 = "SELECT COL_66 FROM tbl_name";
$result6 = mysql_query($query5);
if (!$result6) {
echo 'Query5 Failed: ' . mysql_error();
exit;
}
$row2 = mysql_fetch_row($result6);
```

I was trying to use

```
$picture = implode(",", $row2);
echo $picture[0];
```

And then I tried

```
$picture = explode(",", $row2);
echo $picture[0];
```

The return for implode is:

```
h
```

The return for explode is:

```
Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in ...
```

I'm assuming this is because there are no quotation marks around the img URL's(?)

Am I doing something wrong? Does it have anything to do with the quotation marks?

Thanks for reading & any help!

Comment: Stop storing it in that way and google about "many-to-many" relations in RDBMS

Comment: Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php). That joins an array of strings together into one string.

You need the opposite...[`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), which takes a string and splits it into an array.

You'll need to loop through your result set, like this:

```
while ($row2 = $mysql_fetch_row($result6)) {
    // assuming the column you need is the first column returned by the query
    $picture = explode(',', $row2[0]);
    echo $picture[0];

    // OR
    list($picture) = explode(',', $row2[0]);
    echo $picture;
}
```

As @zerkms said in the question comments, you should store this differently. This looks to me like a one-to-many relationship, so you should store these URLs in a separate table. Something like this:

```
+-------------+-----------------------------+---------+
| mainTableID | URL                         | primary |
+-------------+-----------------------------+---------+
| 1           | http://website.com/img1.jpg | 1       |
| 1           | http://website.com/img2.jpg | 0       |
| 1           | http://website.com/img3.jpg | 0       |
+-------------+-----------------------------+---------+
```

`mainTableID` is a foreign key to your main table and `primary` is a bit field that indicates which one is your "main image". This is called **normalization**.

Comment: I get this error.Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in ...

Comment: @LawrenceShea: `$row2` is an array. Each entry represents one column from your query. So not only will you need to specify which column you want to get (if it's the first column returned by the query, it'll be `$row2[0]`), but you'll also want to loop through the rows. See my updated answer.

Comment: SCRATCH THAT! I'm a moron. I totally overlooked the loop & also the extra $ in $mysql_fetch_row

Comment: @LawrenceShea: No problem. Glad I helped. If you didn't see it already, make sure you take a look at my last update, which gives you an idea for a better schema design.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

The first $row is an array where [0] is the whole row (with only one column).
$picture is the first part of the first row.

$row2 = mysql_fetch_row($result6);

$picture = explode(",", $row2[0]);

Comment: I think you're confusing what a "row" is versus what a "column" is. `$row2` is the whole row, which is an array of **columns** returned by the query. There is only one column in the query, so it's an array with only one entry. `$picture` is the first part of the first **column**.